# Adams-Bashforth methods in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write Adams-Bashforth methods ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Two-step_Adams.E2.80.93Bashforth ) in Python. Actually my code is slower than Euler method and gave worst results. Can you help me to upgrade my code?

```
s1 = [1]
s2 = [-0.5, 1.5]
s3 = [5./12, -4./3, 23./12]
s4 = [-3./8, 37/24, -59./24, 55./24]
s5 = [251./720, -637./360, 109./30, -1387./360, 1901./720]


def adams_bashforth(f, ta, tb, xa, n, sn=s5):
    last_n = []
    h = (tb - ta) / float(n)
    t = ta
    x = xa
    # first n steps made by Euler method
    for i in range(len(sn)):
        last_n.append(h * f(t, x))
        x += last_n[-1]
        t += h
    # Adams-Bashforth method
    for i in range(n):
        x += h * sum([last_n[i] * sn[i] for i in range(len(sn))])
        last_n = last_n[1:]
        last_n.append(f(t, x))
        t += h
    return x

def f(t, x):
    return t * sqrt(x)

print adams_bashforth(f, 0, 1, 10, 1000, s5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Adams-Bashforth, so I'm just refactoring the Python code that you provided.  It may be possible to obtain much better results by changing the algorithm itself.

You can get a decent speedup (30-40% on my machine, for `n=1M`) by eliminating list copies (`last_n = last_n[1:]`) and appends from your program.  The following is equivalent and uses a list of just `SN` (`=len(sn)`) elements in a circular fashion:

```
def adams_bashforth(f, ta, tb, xa, n, sn=s5):
    h = (tb - ta) / float(n)
    t = ta
    x = xa
    SN = len(sn)
    # first n steps made by Euler method
    last_n = []
    for i in range(SN):
        y = h * f(t, x)
        last_n.append(y)
        x += y
        t += h
    # Adams-Bashforth method
    j = 0
    for i in range(n):
        ss = 0
        for s in sn:
            ss += last_n[j] * s
            j += 1
            if j >= SN: j = 0
        x += h * ss        
        last_n[j] = f(t, x)
        t += h
        j += 1
        if j >= SN: j = 0
    return x
```

Comment: Thanks! It's much faster than my version . Unfortunately, I still have a problem with to big error in my results.